# Alphanumeric base conversion in Ruby

Tags: ruby

This is another Codewars Ruby problem that's got me stumped:

> Description:
>   In this kata you have to implement a base converter, which converts between arbitrary bases / alphabets. Here are some pre-defined alphabets:

```
bin='01'
oct='01234567'
dec='0123456789'
hex='0123456789abcdef'
allow='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
allup='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
alpha='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
alphanum='0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
```

> The function convert() should take an input (string), the source alphabet (string) and the target alphabet (string). You can assume that the input value always consists of characters from the source alphabet. You don't need to validate it.

```
Examples:
convert("15", dec, bin) #should return "1111"
convert("15", dec, oct) #should return "17"
convert("1010", bin, dec) #should return "10"
convert("1010", bin, hex) #should return "a"
convert("0", dec, alpha) #should return "a"
convert("27", dec, allow) #should return "bb"
convert("hello", allow, hex) #should return "320048"
```

> Additional Notes:
>
> The maximum input value can always be encoded in a number without loss of precision in JavaScript. In Haskell, intermediate results will probably be to large for Int.
>   The function must work for any arbitrary alphabets, not only the pre-defined ones.
>   You don't have to consider negative numbers.

I've been playing with this for a couple of days and managed to get the numeric-base-conversion portion working. It's the alphabetical part of it that I can't figure out how to approach, and my brain is tired from trying. Here's my code:

```
def convert(input, source, target)
      bases = {
      :bin      => '01',
      :oct      => '01234567',
      :dec      => '0123456789',
      :hex      => '0123456789abcdef',
      :allow    => 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
      :allup    => 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
      :alpha    => 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
      :alphanum => '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
      }
  base_from , base_to = 0    
  src_num_switch = 1 if source == bases[:bin] || [:oct] || [:dec] || [:hex] 
  tgt_num_switch = 1 if target == bases[:bin] || [:oct] || [:dec] || [:hex] 
  src_num_switch = 0 if source == bases[:allow] || [:allup] || [:alpha] || [:alphanum] 
  tgt_num_switch = 0 if target == bases[:allow] || [:allup] || [:alpha] || [:alphanum] 
  if source == bases[:bin] then base_from = 2
  elsif source == bases[:oct] then base_from = 8
  elsif source == bases[:dec] then base_from = 10
  elsif source == bases[:hex] then base_from = 16
  elsif source == bases[:allow] then base_from = 13
  elsif source == bases[:allup] then base_from = 13
  elsif source == bases[:alpha] then base_from = 13
  elsif source == bases[:alphanum] then base_from = 13
  else puts ":( no source match found :(" 
  end
  if target == bases[:bin] then puts base_to = 2
  elsif target == bases[:oct] then base_to = 8
  elsif target == bases[:dec] then base_to = 10
  elsif target == bases[:hex] then base_to = 16
  elsif target == bases[:allow] then base_to = 13
  elsif target == bases[:allup] then base_to = 13
  elsif target == bases[:alpha] then base_to = 13
  elsif target == bases[:alphanum] then base_to = 13
  else puts ":( no target match found :(" 
  end
  if base_from == base_to then 
    return input
  elsif src_num_switch == 1 && tgt_num_switch == 1 then
    return Integer(input, base_from).to_s(base_to)
  elsif src_num_switch == 0 && tgt_num_switch == 0 then
    return Integer(input, base_from).to_s(base_to)  
# ### # :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::



  else
    puts "ouch, something broke"
  end

end
```

I've got everything down to the "# ### #" portion working for me. Can anyone give me an idea of how to do the alpha-base portion? I've tried the following but had no luck:

```
 if base_from == base_to then return input
  elsif src_num_switch == 1 && tgt_num_switch == 1 then
    return Integer(input, base_from).to_s(base_to)    
  elsif src_num_switch == 1 && tgt_num_switch == 0 then
    if target == bases[:allup] then return bases[input.index].to_s.upcase
    elsif target == bases[:allow] then return bases[input.index].to_s.downcase 
    end
  end

  elsif src_num_switch == 0 && tgt_num_switch == 1 then
        return input.index.to_s(base_to)        
  elsif src_num_switch == 0 && tgt_num_switch == 0 then
    return Integer(input, base_from).to_s(base_to)    

  else
    puts "ouch, something broke"
  end
```

This one too:

```
  elsif src_num_switch == 1 && tgt_num_switch == 0 then                      # number-base to alphanumeric-base
    if target == bases[:allup] then 
      return bases[input.index].to_s.upcase
    elsif target == bases[:allow] then 
      return bases[input.index].to_s.downcase 
    end
  elsif src_num_switch == 0 && tgt_num_switch == 1 then                      # alpha-base to number-base
        return input.index.to_s(base_to)
```

Comment: Are all these code related to your problem? It's better to narrow the problem down, include only the smallest code that's necessary for your specific question.

Comment: sorry, can you give us a test case here that fails?  You've supplied a lot of code.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and *the shortest code necessary to reproduce it* in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Answer (score 1):

There may be a very clever built-in Ruby solution, but I would guess based on the custom alphabets describing the number systems that there is not. So, I don't have a direct answer to how to complete your code, but I would suggest a slightly different strategy.

#### Converting from a decimal

Any number system can be converted from the decimal system like so:

```
vals_in_system = system.length
output_in_system = []
while (decimal_num != 0)
  index_of_next_val = decimal_num % system.length
  output_in_system.unshift(system[index_of_next_val])
  decimal_num = decimal_num / vals_in_system # truncating is desired here
end
```

It's a bit tricky. This algorithm first tries to determine what value it has to put in the last position (which has the most granularity in whatever number system you're using). E.g. if you were to represent 12 in decimal (yes, it already is, but using this algorithm), a 2 has to go in the last position - no number you put in the tens place or higher will otherwise help you represent 12. If you were to represent 3 in binary, a 1 has to go in the last position of the binary - nothing you put in the next position will get you to a 3. Once it determines this, it can divide by the base, which will leave you with the number you would use to calculate the remaining positions. For example, if you were to represent 123 in decimal, dividing by 10 (the decimal base) and truncating would give you 12. 12 is the representation of the original number except for the final position (which was chopped off by dividing by the base). (I realize this isn't the clearest explanation so let me know if you have questions.) Some examples:

E.g. the decimal number 15 can be converted to binary:

1. 15 % 2 = 1 # last position
2. 15 / 2 = 7
3. 7 % 2 = 1 # next to last position
4. 7 / 2 = 3
5. 3 % 2 = 1 # 3rd to last position
6. 3 / 2 = 1
7. 1 % 2 = 1 # 4th to last position
8. 1 / 2 = 0 # stop

That's kinda boring, you just get 1111. Try something a little more interesting, like 10:

1. 10 % 2 = 0 # last position
2. 10 / 2 = 5
3. 5 % 2 = 1 # next to last position
4. 5 / 2 = 2
5. 2 % 2 = 0 # 3rd to last position
6. 2 / 2 = 1
7. 1 % 2 = 1 # 4th to last position
8. 1 / 2 = 0 # stop

And you get 1010, which is indeed 10 in binary. You can do this with any of those alphabets.

#### Converting to a decimal

Similarly, any number system can be converted to a decimal by doing the opposite:

```
vals_in_system = from.length
output_in_decimal = 0
val.each_char do |next_val|
  output_in_decimal *= vals_in_system
  output_in_decimal += from.index(next_val)
end
```

This is easier to understand than the "from decimal" algorithm. Consider if you were to apply this to the decimal number 123. This algorithm is essentially doing this equation

```
((1 * 10) + 2) * 10) + 3
```

or, much easier to read:

```
1 * (10 * 10) + 2 * (10) + 3
```

Just iteratively. It works for other number systems, by replacing the 10 with the base of the number system (i.e. the number of values the number system contains). The only other magic it does it converts a value in the number system into a decimal number using `.index`.

E.g. converting "bcdl" to decimal from their "allow" system. Using a 0-index, b = the 1st position, c = 2nd, d = 3rd, l = 11th

1. Start with 0
2. Multiply by the number system base, which is 26 (26 letters in the lowercase alphabet) = 0
3. Add the decimal value of b (1) => 1
4. 1 * 26 = 26
5. Add decimal value of c (2) => 28
6. 28 * 26 => 728
7. Add decimal value of d (3) => 731
8. 731 * 26 => 19006
9. Add decimal value of l (11) => 19017  That's the decimal notation for "bcdl".

#### Putting it together

Once you have converters to and from decimal, you can write a pretty straightforward wrapper to handle every situation (I put `DEC` in a constant to make it visible in this method, it's the same as `dec`):

```
def convert(val, from, to)
  case
  when from == to then val
  when from == DEC then convert_from_dec(val, to)
  when to == DEC then convert_to_dec(val, from)
  else
    convert_from_dec(convert_to_dec(val, from), to)
  end
end
```

After that, you mostly have to deal with edge cases.

As I said, not a direct answer to your question, but it seems like you'll have to use this general approach for the alpha number systems, at which point you may as well use it for everything :)

Answer (score 1):

I honestly tried not to look at alexcavalli's solution, but in the end came to exact same algorithm with a different code. So for explanation why it works look at his much more explained answer. Here it's only code, written in a way if you save it under base_converter.rb name you can run it as:

```
$ ruby ../base_converer.rb 123 hex dec #=> 291
```

```rb
bases = {
  bin: '01',
  oct: '01234567',
  dec: '0123456789',
  hex: '0123456789abcdef',
  allow: 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
  allup: 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
  alpha: 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
  alphanum: '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
}

def to_int(num, src)
  src_map = src.split('').map.with_index.to_h
  num.reverse.each_char.with_index.sum{ |c, i| src_map[c] * (src.size ** i) }
end

def from_int(num, dst)
  res = []
  while num > 0
    res << dst[num % dst.size]
    num /= dst.size
  end

  res.join.reverse
end

def convert(num, src, dst)
  from_int(to_int(num, src), dst)
end

if ARGV.size > 2
  puts convert(ARGV[0], bases[ARGV[1].to_sym], bases[ARGV[2].to_sym])
end
```